# Full Exceptional Collection of Vector Bundles for Toric Varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

[Kawamata showed](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503102.pdf) the derived category of coherent sheaves on a smooth projective toric variety has a full exceptional collection consisting of sheaves. I was wondering if it is know whether every smooth projective toric variety has a full exceptional collection consisting of vector bundles?

For context, King conjectured that a smooth complete toric variety has a full strong exceptional collection consisting of line bundles. This turns out to be false. For example, [Hill and Perling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602258.pdf) constructed example of smooth projective toric variety which does not have a full strong exceptional collection consisting of line bundles. It seems significant work has gone into producing additional counterexamples, as well as, proving the conjecture under additional hypotheses.

I am wondering whether a similar conjecture might be true if we drop the strong hypothesis and allow vector bundles instead of line bundles.

Update: It was recently pointed out to me that Kawamata's paper contains a slight misstatement and the the full exceptional collection does not consist of just sheaves, but instead complexes of sheaves. See Remark 7 in the [*published version*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/michigan-mathematical-journal/volume-62/issue-2/Derived-categories-of-toric-varieties-II/10.1307/mmj/1370870376.full) of "Derived categories of toric varieties II".

Comment: As far as I know the existence of such an exceptional collection is not known. For some negative results see also arXiv:1010.3755.